# Using Android AWS SDK trasfer image to s3 without secertkey

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, image-uploading, awss3transfermanager

I would thinking  image is upload to s3 without secret key in app. **Policy and signature** are getting from server because security reason.If any possible is AWS SDK ? or any idea to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I'm having trouble understanding the question but it sounds like you want to be able to upload an image to S3 without including your secret key in your app. Cognito was actually made for this exact use case, so you should definitely check it out [here](http://aws.amazon.com/cognito/?sc_channel=PS&sc_campaign=AWS_Free_Tier_2013_T&sc_country=US&sc_publisher=Google&sc_medium=b_test_cognito_bmm-brand_amazon_cognito&sc_content=47718848442&sc_detail=%2Baws%20%2Bcognito&sc_category=mobile_services&sc_segment=cognito&sc_matchtype=[matchtype])